# Global JavaScript variable with OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Why is this working?

```
function addMap() {
  var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([29.5646, 44.1575]),
    zoom: 4
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: view
  });
}
```

...and this isn't?

```
var view = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([29.5646, 44.1575]),
  zoom: 4
});

function addMap() {
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: view
  });
}
```

I thought if variable is outside function, it's global variable and it can be used from all other places.

Comment: Define "not working"?  Is `ol.View` available to be used as a constructor function when it runs, or is it only ready by the time `addMap` is actually called?

Comment: I wanted to create another function, which is using view and changing rotate for example
    `function angleRight(){
    view.setRotation(view.getRotation+1);
    }`
and call it when I press button.

Comment: You still didn't explain *how* it is "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that you are running javascript on the document before the document has been loaded so

1. move your javascript code to the end of the body or
2. you can do all this in

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   var view = new ol.View({
   center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([29.5646, 44.1575]),
   zoom: 4
   }
   ```

Comment: It was that! Thanks